# Unit tests: where to stop?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

The classical solution if you have a concrete implementation of a dependency in a class you want to test is: add a layer of indirection where you have full control.

So it comes to adding more and more of indirection layers (interfaces that can be stubs/mocks in unit tests).

But: somewhere in my tests I must have the "real" implementation of my dependency. So what about this? Test? Don't test?

Take this example:

I had some dependencies on paths that I need in my application. So I extracted an interface, `IPathProvider` (that I can fake in my tests). Here is the implementation:

```
public interface IPathProvider
{
    string AppInstallationFolder { get; }
    string SystemCommonApplicationDataFolder { get; }
}
```

The concrete implementation `PathProvider` looks like this:

```
public class PathProvider : IPathProvider
{
    private string _appInstallationFolder;
    private string _systemCommonApplicationDataFolder;

    public string AppInstallationFolder
    {
        get
        {
            if (_appInstallationFolder == null)
            {
                try
                {
                    _appInstallationFolder =
                        Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new MyException("Error reading Application-Installation-Path.", ex);
                }
            }
            return _appInstallationFolder;
        }
    }

    public string SystemCommonApplicationDataFolder
    {
        get
        {
            if (_systemCommonApplicationDataFolder == null)
            {
                try
                {
                    _systemCommonApplicationDataFolder =
                        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new MyException("Error reading System Common Application Data Path.", ex);
                }
            }
            return _systemCommonApplicationDataFolder;
        }
    }
}
```

Do you test such code and if, how?

Comment: Here's some food for thought regarding unit tests: http://www.rbcs-us.com/documents/Why-Most-Unit-Testing-is-Waste.pdf

Answer (score 2):

That `PathProvider` class seems a lot like a database repository class - it integrates with an external system (e.g., filesystem, database, etc).

These classes live at the boundaries of your system - other classes depend on them, and they depend solely on an external system. They connect your system to the external world.

As such, they're subject to [integration testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing) - *not* unit testing.

I usually just tag my tests (e.g. with xUnit's `Trait` attribute) to keep them separate from regular tests, and so I can disable them when running in isolation (e.g. without a database). An alternative would be to separate them into a whole new project in the same solution, but I personally think that's overkill.

```
[Fact, Trait("Category", "Integration")]
public void ReturnsCorrectAppInstallationFolder()
{
    // Arrange
    var assemblyFilename = Path.GetFilename(typeof(SomeType).Assembly.Location);
    var provider = new PathProvider();

    // Act
    var location = provider.AppInstallationFolder;

    // Assert
    Assert.NotEmpty(Directory.GetFiles(location, assemblyFilename))
}
```

Comment: I agree with your statement, but this is not really a suitable answer to the question. He's not asking what type of test this would be...

Comment: @JamieRees I guess I ended up responding to the "Do you test such code" part, but not to the "how".

Comment: I think this would have been better suited as a comment. But you didn't answer the do you test this code. You just stated what type of test you would class it as.

Comment: So, in this case, my code coverage tool tells me this is not tested in my unit test --> I like to test it somehow (and even if it's not a unit test but an integration test). How would you setup this?

Comment: By the way: you find a lot of good literature aiming at Unit Tests but I couldn't find some aiming at integration tests (like this case would be)

Comment: Or one more thought/question: how do you manage these "external world connectors" in your projects? Are you putting them in a special folder/namespace/...?

Comment: @JamieRees I've added more detail and an example of what I would do.

Comment: @joerg Regarding the management of the connectors - well, that really depends on the project, and on what side of the bed I wake up. I've had DAOs in their own namespace, I've also had to separate DAOs into a whole new project because they were gonna be reused by other projects, it depends. But I would start with a small degree of separation (i.e. namespace). Also, I wouldn't lump all the connectors into *one* namespace - they're not really related to each other.

Comment: @dcastro: thanks for your example, I see what you mean... your example will fail in this special case because `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` is called out of the test-environment; thanks also for your ideas of separating the DAO's

Comment: @joerg that's a good point - feel free to edit my answer and correct the code above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86884/discussion-between-joerg-and-dcastro).

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on your definition of 'unit'. In the case where a class is used as a unit then the answer is yes. However, testing individual classes has very limited business value unless you're developing a class library of some kind.

Another alternative it to define a unit as being a user-level (or system) requirement. A test for this kind of unit will be along the lines of: given user input X, test for system output Y. Units defined in this way have definite, measurable business value that can be traced to user requirements.

For example, when using [user stories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_story) you may have a requirements such as:

> As an administrator, I want to install the package to a specific folder.

This may have a number of associated scenarios to cover different permissible and prohibited folders. Each of these will have a unit test that provides the user input and verifies the output.

> Given: The user has specified `C:\Program Files\MyApp` as the install
>   folder.
>
> When: The installer has run.
>
> Then: The `C:\Program Files\MyApp` exists on the drive and all of the
>   application files are present in that location.

When unit testing at a class interface level as you appear to be doing, you can easily end up with your software design tightly coupled to your unit test framework and implementation, rather than to your users' requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The two answers have a lot of value, but I'll add one more thing, which I believe to be of big importance.

I have a feeling that people often get tied up in discussions about what should tested and what should not. That something should be treated as unit or it shouldn't. That it's an integration or not.

**Generally**, the goal of unit tests is to **make sure our code works as intended**. IMO we should test everything (whatever we are able to), that can get broken. Organizing it into some formal type of test and naming it is needed, but is of secondary importance to the test itself. My advice would be, that if you have any doubts, always ask yourself the question: **"Am I afraid that it can be broken?"**. So... "where to stop"? **Where you are not afraid of the functionality getting broken**.

And back to your **specific case**. As @dcastro noticed, this does look a lot as a case of integration testing, rather than classic logic unit testing. Regardless of how we name it though - can it be broken? Yes it can. Should it be tested?
 It MAY be tested, although I'd be far from naming it crucial. There is little own added logic and the complexity is low. Would I test it? Yes, if I had the time to do so. How would I do it? @dcastro 's example code is the way I'd approach the problem.